# How to trigger Model Validation inside modal? .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal, .net-5

i Have problem when i try the model validation by trying to fill the form by false.
And when i try to submit with the wrong value (not valid by model validator) it redirects to the page (without model).

Here's the screenshot :
[Customer Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmCXQ.png)
[redirect to Customer Create Page when i submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9J0y.png)

Here's the code

CONTROLLER

```
  //POST CREATE
    [HttpPost]
    [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Models.Customer obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Customers.Add(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(obj);
    }

    //GET DELETE
    public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var obj = _db.Customers.Find(id);
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return PartialView(obj);
    }
```

Model

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Nama Customer")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(81, ErrorMessage ="Tidak boleh melebihi 81 Karakter")]
    public string Nama { get; set; }
    
    public string Alamat { get; set; }
    [Phone]
    [Required]
    public string Telp { get; set; }
}
```

Index.HTML Button Create

```
<button id="btnAddCustomer" class="btn btn-primary">Tambah Customer</button>
```

JS

```
 @section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAddCustomer").on("click", function (e) {
        var $buttonClicked = $(this);
        //var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
        var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Customer")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: null,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#modalBody').html(data);
                $('#modalCustomer').modal(options);
                $('#modalCustomer').modal('show');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });
    })
});
```

CREATE CSHTML

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
<div class="border p-3">
    
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-4">

        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h2 class="text-black-50 pl-3">Add Customer</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">

        </div>
        
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Nama"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Nama" class="form-control" />
                        
                        <span asp-validation-for="Nama" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Telp"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Telp" class="form-control" />
                        
                        <span asp-validation-for="Telp" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Alamat"></label>
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Alamat" class="form-control" />
                        @*validasi form*@
                        <span asp-validation-for="Alamat" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-6">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">

                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-2 row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info w-75" value="create" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-danger w-75">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you (:

Answer (score 0):

> And when i try to submit with the wrong value (not valid by model
> validator) it redirects to the page (without model).

You use `return View(obj);` when modelstate is not valid. So it will return view with model and the view name should be the action name(Create) if you do not specific view name. So this result is correct by using your code.

Here is a working demo：

Index.cshtml:

```
<button id="btnAddCustomer" class="btn btn-primary"> Tambah Customer</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalCustomer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAddCustomer").on("click", function (e) {
        var $buttonClicked = $(this);
        //var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
        var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Customer")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: null,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#modalBody').html(data);
                //$('#modalCustomer').modal(options);
                $('#modalCustomer').modal('show');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });
    })
});
    </script>
}
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@model Customer
@{
    Layout = null;         //be sure add this...
}
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="border p-3">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group row"><div class="col-4"></div><div class="col-4"><h2 class="text-black-50 pl-3">Add Customer</h2></div><div class="col-4"></div></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Nama"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Nama" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Nama" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Telp"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Telp" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Telp" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="col-12 form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Alamat"></label>
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Alamat" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Alamat" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row"><div class="col-6"></div><div class="col-6"></div><div class="col-6"></div></div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-2 row">
                        <div class="col"> 
                                     @*change here..........*@
                            <input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-info w-75" value="create" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-danger w-75">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS in Create.cshtml:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#modalCustomer #btn', function () {
        var options = {};
        options.type = "POST";
        options.url = "/Customer/create";
        options.dataType = "JSON";
        options.cache = false;
        options.async = true;
        options.data = $("form").serialize();
        options.success = function (data) {
            //do your stuff...
            $('#modalCustomer').modal('hide');
             //if you don't want to stay in Index
             //add the following code..
            // window.location.href = "/home/privacy";
        };
        options.error = function (res) {
            $('#modalBody').html(res.responseText);
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    });
</script>
```

**Update:**

If modelstate is invalid, it will get into `options.error` and display the error message in modal. If modelstate is valid, it will get into `options.success`, you could redirect by using `window.location.href` or hide the modal by  `$('#modalCustomer').modal('hide');`, just do your stuff.

Backend code should be like below:

```
[HttpPost]
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(Customers obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Customers.Add(obj);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { success = true });   //change this...
    }
    return View(obj);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i still get confused to fill the JS in create "do your stuff" to validate and insert the new row. So what i must fill with that model?